# ¿Cómo exportar de Excel a CSV con caracteres japoneses (Unicode)?

Tags: excel, csv, utf-8

Necesito exportar archivos Excel a formato CSV, pero los kanjis japoneses no los reconoce y en el CSV aparecen sustituidos por `?`.

¿Hay alguna forma de que los reconozca?

Answer (score 1):

Realiza los siguientes pasos:

1. Carga el archivo excel en Google Sheets del google Drive.
2. Descarga el archivo en CSV verificando que el formato tenga Unicode UTF-8.

Esta información la obtuve de [Microsoft Excel Won't Show Japanese Characters](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/microsoft-excel-wont-show-japanese-characters-77317.html).

Espero sea de ayuda.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en la exportación a CSV del Excel. Está no tiene ninguna opción para configurar el `encoding` final del archivo, seguramente se salva como `ascii` plano, dónde un carácter es un byte. Cuando hablamos de manejar caracteres como los japoneses entre muchísimos otros más, tenemos que empezar a manejar `encodings` como `utf-8` o `Unicode`, donde un carácter puede ser mayor que un byte. Al salvar un Excel a un `csv` toda la riqueza de un caracter `unicode` se pierde por que Excel lo transforma en un carácter de un solo byte, el hecho que se vean como `?` es justamente causa de esto.

No existe ninguna limitación técnica por la que no se pueda salvar un `csv` como `utf-8` o `unicode` por lo que parece increíble que Microsoft no haya modificado esto, pero es así.

La solución que ya te ofrecieron es un "workaround" al problema totalmente válido, también una alternativa es salvar el archivo como `"Texto Unicode"`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto te va a generar un archivo con dicho `encoding`, por lo que mantenemos el formato original y cuyas columnas en vez de estar separadas por la coma lo estarán por el `TAB`, es decir un `CHAR(9)`. No debiera ser complicado luego importarlo simplemente modificando el separador de columnas.

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido